# How do I post to a new php page with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to post the element information that jQuery pulls, when a user clicks on table cell, to a new page that will use that information (an id in this case) in a sql query. i.e., the user clicks a cell and the job he/she clicks has an id of 25, that is to be passed to my php page that queries the database for the job with that id and then populates the page with said information. The user can then alter the information from the query and submit it to update the database table. I have the id from the click function and a success alert tells me that the info was posted. The problem is that when the page is opened it states that the posted name index is undefined.
Here is my script to get the information:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("table.jobs tbody td#job").click(function()
            {
                var $this = $(this);
                var col   = $this.text();
                var LeftCellText = $this.prev().text();
                if (col == '')
                alert("Please pick another column");
                else
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"../php/jobUpdate.php",
                    data:"name=" + LeftCellText,
                    success: function()
                    {
                        window.location = "../php/jobUpdate.php";
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and here is the simple php page it is sending to:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;
```

I am new to jQuery, and I cannot figure out why this is not working?

Comment: If you are going to redirect on success there is no advantage to using ajax, you are just going to make 2 requests to the server instead of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment to my previous post, it seems that you don't need ajax at all. You just need a form in your HTML:

```
<form id="MyForm" action="../php/jobUpdate.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="jobID" name="yourJobID">
</form>
```

Note that forms are invisible until you put something visible inside them.

You can have select controls (dropdowns) in there, or all form elements can be invisible by using hidden input fields (like the HTML just above), which you can populate using jQuery. Code to do that would look something like this:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("table.jobs tbody td#job").click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var col   = $this.text();
            var LeftCellText = $this.prev().text();

            //Set value of hidden field in form. This is how
            //data will be passed to jobUpdate.php, via its `name` param
            $('#jobID').val(LeftCellText); 

            if (col == '')
                alert("Please pick another column");
            else
                $('#myForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you add more values to your form to send over to jobUpdate.php, just ensure that each  element has a name, such as `<input type="text" name="selectedJobType">` (this element, type="text", would be visible on screen).

In the jobUpdate.php file, you would get these values thus:

```
$SJT = $_POST['selectedJobType'];
$id = $_POST["yourJobID"];

//Use these vars in MySQL search, then display some HTML based on results
```

Note that the `key` referenced in the $_POST[] array (selectedJobType / yourJobID) is always identical to the `name` specified in the HTML tag. These names are case sensitive (and spelling counts, too).

Hope this isn't TMI, just wish to cover all the bases.

Comment: Thanks again gibberish! Unfortunately I am still getting the 'Notice: Undefined index: jobid' message. I can see that it is working as I need it to, except for the fact that it is not passing the value. What can be going wrong? I appreciate all the help, but this is starting to drive me crazy.

Comment: Thanks again gibberish! I just got it. Part of the issue is that I am building the table using pear HTML_TABLE. It took a little bit of manipulation of the tags, but I got it thanks to your help! Thanks and thanks, and YOU ROCK!

Comment: Ok, i was a little too happy. It is passing the information, but only for one cell. No matter which job I click on, it passes the id for the first job in the first table instead of the id that is to the left of the clicked cell. What now???

Comment: OMG! That was a pain! Thank you very much for the help gibberish!!! As I said, a little altering due to using pear...but I got it. Your solution was the correct one, I just had to fit it into an auto-generated table. Again, you Rock! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you use ajax, the second page `../php/jobUpdate.php` processes the data sent by the first page, and returns a value (or even a huge string of html, if you want).

The first page receives the new data in the ajax routine's `success` function and can then update the current page. The updating part happens in the `success:` function, so you're on the right track.

But in your success function, you are redirecting the user to the 2nd page -- after already being there and processing the data. *Redirecting* them is probably not what you want to do.

Try replacing this:

```
                success: function()
                {
                    window.location = "../php/jobUpdate.php";
                }
```

with this:

```
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                }
```

If you want to see how to update the first page with the data received via ajax, try adding an empty DIV to your html, like this:

```
<div id="somestuff"></div>
```

Then, in the `success:` function of the ajax routine, do this:

```
$('#somestuff').html(data);
```

(Note that the term "data" can be any name at all, it only needs to match the name used in the function param. For example:

```
success: function(whatzup) {
    alert(whatzup);
}
```

Comment: Thanks gibberish! You code and suggestion are good, but they are not what I am going for. When a user is looking at my page they see a calendar of jobs. When they click the job title I need the jquery to acknowledge the click by retrieving the id field (LeftCellText) and posting (i.e. sending the value) to the next page (jobUpdate.php) where I will use the value to construct a sql query and return a record that the user can alter and then submit. That is why I am trying to redirect. I don't need to update the current page, but open another form with the passed value of the clicked item.

Comment: That's even easier. See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

On your success function causing the window to reload will delete any of the variables passed in via .ajax.

What you can try is returning the data and use it in the existing page.

```
success: function(msg) {
     $('#someDiv').append(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the index is not defined is because you are using a string in the data-argument, however, that is actually an array-like object. :)

```
data: { name: col }
```

that should be the line you need to change. Otherwise I have not seen any problems. Also if I can give you a little idea, I wouldn't use POST actually. In fact, I'd use GET. I can not confirm if that is saver or not, but using $_SERVER["HTTP_REFFERER"] you can check from where that request is coming to determine if you want to let it pass or not.

The way I would suggest is, that you sent the ID in a GET-request and have the PHP code return the data using `json_decode()`. Now in jQuery, you can use `$.getJSON(url, function(data){})` - which is, for one, shorter and a bit faster.

Since you probably will crop the URL yourself here, make sure that you use a function like `intVal()` in JS to make sure you are sending an intenger instead of a malicious string :)